# Why does using a ternary to assign a constant return an optional in swift?

Tags: swift

Specifically, a ternary that guarantees a non-nil value or a string literal.

Inside my class:

```
var title: String?
```

later...

```
let currentTitle = (self.title != nil) ? self.title : "Hello world"
```

`currentTitle` is an optional, even though it should be guaranteed a value - "Hello world". Why?

Comment: Comparing with `nil` doesn't unwrap an optional; you need to do that yourself. The tool you're looking for here is the nil coalescing operator: `let currentTitle = title ?? "Hello world"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know it will always have a value, but the type system doesn't know that. The initializer expression, when reduced to types, looks like `Bool ? String? : String` (which then gets converted to `Bool ? String? : String?` so both arms match).

The proper way to write this is

```
let currentTitle = self.title ?? "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `self.title` is an optional and it's one of the result subexpressions of the ternary operator. Swift tries to reconcile the types of the two result subexpressions to determine a type for the expression as a whole and, given a `String?` and a `String`, it has to choose `String?` and so coerces the string literal to an optional. Try force unwrapping `self.title`:

```
let currentTitle = (self.title != nil) ? self.title! : "Hello world"
```

Comment: Please do not encourage force-unwrapping like this. There's always a better way. `self.title ?? "Hello world"` is the correct solution here.

Comment: Thank you Ken. You perfectly answered my question, but Kevin's way seems cleaner and more direct